# Proof of decimal expansion

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If the denominator of a rational number contains only 2 and 5 as prime factors then the decimal expansion of the rational number is terminating.  How can I Prove this

Comment: You can multiply top and bottom by the same integer so that the new denominator is a power of $10$.

Comment: See also [Characterising reals with terminating decimal expansions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198615/characterising-reals-with-terminating-decimal-expansions).

Answer (score 2):

First, let's observe that any terminating decimal fraction is equal to a simple fraction with a denominator which is a power of $10$ and vice versa.

Now, let $f=p/q$, where $p$ and $q$ are integers and $q$ contains only 2 and 5 as prime factors.  Then $q$ can be written as

$$
   q = 2^m\cdot 5^n,
$$

where $m$ and $n$ are non-negative integers.  If $m=n$, then $q=10^n$, and $f=p/10^n$. If $m>n$, then multiplying both the numerator and the denominator of $f$ by $5^{m-n}$, we get

$$
   f =\frac{p\cdot 5^{m-n}}{2^m\cdot 5^n\cdot 5^{m-n}}
    = \frac{p\cdot 5^{m-n}}{2^m\cdot 5^m}
    = \frac{p\cdot 5^{m-n}}{10^m}.
$$

The case $m<n$ can be done the same way by multiplying both the numerator and the denominator of $f$ by $2^{n-m}$.  Thus, for any choice of $m$ and $n$, $f$ can be rewritten as a fraction with a power of $10$ in the denominator, or a terminating decimal fraction. QED.

Comment: A trick to avoid considering three separate cases: multiply by $2^n \cdot 5^m$.  But resolving into cases is probably more transparent and natural.